# Issue with creating URL to invoke email functionality in Lightning

Tags: lightning, button

I keep getting this error:  The value of the `p3_lkid` parameter contains a character that is not allowed or the value exceeds the maximum allowed length. Remove the character from the parameter value or reduce the value length and resubmit. If the error still persists, report it to our Customer Support team. Provide the URL of the page you were requesting as well as any other related information.

We are using Lighting. My intent is when someone clicks on the button on the opportunity layout, it sends an email to two individuals and uses the classic HTML email template. Please note that my logic had the real email addresses. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

`/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p3_lkid={!Opportunity.Id}&retURL=%2F{!Opportunity.Id}&p6="Special Offer: "&{!Opportunity.Special_Offer__c}&"-Account: "&{!Opportunity.Account}& "- License Seats: "&{!Opportunity.Licensed_Seats__c}&p24=xxxxx@greathorn.com;xxxxxxxx@greathorn.com&template_id=00X1P000000Z2Hp`

Comment: Can you maybe post the full URL which is returned by salesforce?

Comment: I did not add the button to the page. I am happy to do so. When I click on the preview button on the bottom of Opportunity Custom Button or Link Edit, I receive the following:Unable to Access Page
The value of the "p3_lkid" parameter contains a character that is not allowed or the value exceeds the maximum allowed length. Remove the character from the parameter value or reduce the value length and resubmit. If the error still persists, report it to our Customer Support team. Provide the URL of the page you were requesting as well as any other related information.

Comment: It is likely that your URL is not encoded properly. Can you encode all the dynamic values and put the actual URl generated by Salesforce here.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Those were the only dynamic values that I need. What should I encode? Sorry, I am new to this coding.

Comment: Hello David, the code works! I am hoping you can tell me how to revise it to automatically send when you click the button (without previewing the email) and to define the To field to go to a specific email address (2 employees). I tried creating a contact id for one employee, but it did not work. Thank you! Here is the code: /_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p3_lkid={!Opportunity.Id}&retURL=%2F{!Opportunity.Id}&p24=echaves@greathorn.com;pmcdonald@greathorn.com;jburke@greathorn.com &template_id=00X1P000000Z2Hp &p5= &p2_lkid={Contact.Id}=0031P00001CrWJ1QAN

Comment: To clarify: Hello the emails are going to the correct people using p24 as it is coded. The problem is that it makes you view it and shows the 'To' field as blank. If you disregard the blank 'To' field and hit send the email sends correctly. I would like it to not make you preview the email, but just have it send automatically when someone hits the button. Thank you!